# "len pat." in Lithuanian passport

Tags: documents, lithuania

In this Lithuanian passport, the home location appears to be "len pat." (or "sen pat.")

What does this mean?

[image: Domicile]

For reference, the prior section lists date and location of birth. In other passports, this section shows the person's current location. I'm just unfamiliar with this abbreviation and so is Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gyve namoji vieta means residency. Sen pat apparently means long ago. Probably means residency unknown. According to Google Translate which is sketchy at best of times. I am not Lithuanian so I am seriously guessing.